# Sql Create Table Code Failing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, create-table

For the life of me I don't know why the code below is failing. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

```
Create table #t_dem_pflow               
(unit varchar(10),              
source varchar(7))              

insert into #t_dem_pflow                
(unit, source)              
values  


insert into #t_dem_pflow                
(unit, source)              
values  


/*      

insert into #t_dem_pflow                
(unit, source)              
values          
*/          

Create table #t_dem_decsvc          
(unit varchar(10),          
source varchar(7))          


insert into #t_dem_decsvc           
(unit, source)          
values          


Create table #t_dem_InUnsched           
(unit varchar(10),
source varchar(7))


insert into #t_dem_InUnsched
(unit, source)
values
```

error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'insert'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 22 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'Create'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 32 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'Create'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 38 Incorrect syntax near 'values'.

Comment: Well, I am quite sure SQL Server vices you an error message. Nice you do not care to forward it to us. Let's close this question. Btw., as you ask for input: This is a human error sitting in front of the computer. The poster obviously does not care to read documentation. Example: she ignores the site rules stating that debug requests must be accompanied by the error message (among other things). And the last line is not complete, btw.

Comment: What is the issue with this code? Why you are writing incomplete INSERT statement after creation of table ?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you remove either the MySQL or SQL Server tag.  These are different products, which often require different solutions.

Comment: Can you also explain what you are trying to achieve and where it is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert statements are incomplete..

Your current syntax:

```
insert into #t_dem_InUnsched (unit, source) values
```

What it should be:

```
insert into #t_dem_InUnsched (unit, source) values ('UNIT NAME', '/SOURCE')
```

Comment: Thank you very much NoReceipt4Panda. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Denise could you checkmark/confirm my answer and upvote please? :)